# Iterating over the output of a member function in std::for_each

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, iterator, member-functions

I have a class with an accessor member function that I want to call and apply the result to a functor using std::for_each. I have a working version below that uses a for loop and for_each, but the for_each version is cryptic and cumbersome. Is there a way I can make the for_each version more concise, considering I have access to boost, but not C++11?

```
#if 0
   // for loop version:
   for(value_vector_type::iterator it = values.begin(); it!=values.end(); it++){
     avg(it->getValue());  // I want to put this in a for_each loop
   }
#else
  //  bind version:
  std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), // iterate over all values
    boost::bind(
      boost::mem_fn(&average_type::operator()), // attach the averaging functor to the output of the getvalue call
      &avg, 
      boost::bind(
        boost::mem_fn(&value_wrapper_type::getValue), // bind the getValue call to each element in values
        _1
      )
    )
  );
#endif
```

Here is the full working implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp>

// A value wrapper
template<typename T>
struct Value {
  Value(){}
  Value(const T& value, bool valid = true):m_value(value),m_valid(valid){}

  T getValue(){ return m_value; }
  bool getValid(){ return m_valid; }
  void setValue(const T& value){ m_value = value; }
  void setValid(const T& valid){ m_valid = valid; }

private:
  T m_value;
  bool m_valid;   
};

// Class that calculates the average piecewise
template<typename T>
struct Average {
private:
    T m_numPoints;
    T m_ChannelSum;

public:

    Average() : m_numPoints(0), m_ChannelSum(0.0){}

    void operator()(T value){
        m_numPoints++;
        m_ChannelSum+=value;
    }

    double getAverage(){ return m_ChannelSum/m_numPoints; }
    T getCount(){ return m_numPoints; }
    T getSum(){ return m_ChannelSum; }
};

// Run the average computation on several values
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  typedef int value_type;
  typedef Value<value_type> value_wrapper_type;
  typedef std::vector<value_wrapper_type> value_vector_type;
  value_vector_type values;
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(5));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(7));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(3));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(1));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(2));

  typedef Average<value_type> average_type;
  average_type avg;

#if 0
   // for loop version:
   for(value_vector_type::iterator it = values.begin(); it!=values.end(); it++){
     avg(it->getValue());  // I want to put this in a for_each loop
   }
#else
  //  bind version:
  std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), // iterate over all values
    boost::bind(
      boost::mem_fn(&average_type::operator()), // attach the averaging functor to the output of the getvalue call
      &avg, 
      boost::bind(
        boost::mem_fn(&value_wrapper_type::getValue), // bind the getValue call to each element in values
        _1
      )
    )
  );
#endif    
  std::cout << "Average: " << avg.getAverage() << " Count: " << avg.getCount() << " Sum: " << avg.getSum() << std::endl;
}
```

note: my original question was how to construct a for_each at all, but I've found that solution and a whole new question did not make much sense.

Thanks, all help is really appreciated!

Comment: Why? What does this accomplish that `std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end())/values.size();` wouldn't do?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Averaging is a simplified problem that extracts the essence of my actual problem, which is binding a member function to a functor in a for_each loop.

Comment: My point was also meant to be broader -- that I think you're taking the wrong approach, and you'd be better off asking about what you're really trying to accomplish here, not the details of the (probably wrong, IMO) path you've started to take toward accomplishing that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I agree it may not turn out to be the best approach, but it is certainly beneficial to learn some of the intricacies of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Mathias Gaunard on the boost.users mailing list for pointing me towards this solution:

```
  std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(),
    boost::bind(boost::ref(avg), boost::bind(&value_wrapper_type::getValue, _1))
  );
```

Wrapping `avg` with `boost::ref` is required because otherwise a copy of `avg` is filled out with the results of `getValue()`, rather than `avg` itself.

Here is the full compiled and tested solution:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp>

// A value wrapper
template<typename T>
struct Value {
  Value(){}
  Value(const T& value, bool valid = true):m_value(value),m_valid(valid){}

  T getValue(){ return m_value; }
  bool getValid(){ return m_valid; }
  void setValue(const T& value){ m_value = value; }
  void setValid(const T& valid){ m_valid = valid; }

private:
  T m_value;
  bool m_valid;   
};

// Class that calculates the average piecewise
template<typename T>
struct Average {
private:
    T m_numPoints;
    T m_ChannelSum;

public:
  typedef void result_type;

    Average() : m_numPoints(0), m_ChannelSum(0.0){}

    result_type operator()(T value){
        m_numPoints++;
        m_ChannelSum+=value;
    }

    double getAverage(){ 
    if (m_ChannelSum==0) {
      throw std::logic_error("Cannot get average of zero values");
    }

    return m_ChannelSum/m_numPoints; 
  }
    T getCount(){ return m_numPoints; }
    T getSum(){ return m_ChannelSum; }
};

// Run the average computation on several values
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  typedef int value_type;
  typedef Value<value_type> value_wrapper_type;
  typedef std::vector<value_wrapper_type> value_vector_type;
  value_vector_type values;
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(5));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(7));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(3));
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(1)); 
  values.push_back(value_wrapper_type(2));

  typedef Average<value_type> average_type;
  average_type avg;

#if 0
  // for loop version:
  for(value_vector_type::iterator it = values.begin(); it!=values.end(); it++){
   avg(it->getValue());  // I want to put this in a for_each loop
  }
#else
  //  bind version:
  std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(),
    boost::bind(boost::ref(avg), boost::bind(&value_wrapper_type::getValue, _1))
  );
#endif    
  std::cout << "Average: " << avg.getAverage() << " Count: " << avg.getCount() << " Sum: " << avg.getSum() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using c++11 then you can try

```
for(auto& a: values)
    avg(a->getValue());
```

or

```
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](whatever_type& wt){
    avg(wt->getValue());
});
```

If you are not, then I think that toy have as good as your going to get although formatting wont hurt.

```
for(value_vector_type::iterator it = values.begin(); 
    it!=values.end(); 
    ++it)
{
    avg(it.getValue());  // I want to put this in a for_each loop
}
```

Trying to be too clever with function object and the like can often have the inverse effect of obscuring your code.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to increment iterators with the prefix increment operator, as `++it`.

Comment: @GregHewgill agrees I Didn't see that. fixed

Comment: also the `->` should be `.` (`a` and `wt` are references not iterators)

Comment: @NicolBolas: and what part of "edited 11 hours" don't you understand, that addition to his question was added 3 hours after I made my reply -- i didn't have that knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have C++11 but Boost you could try a `bind()` expression (which would also work with C++2011 as `bind()` is part of C++2011):

```
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), bind(&avg<value_type>, bind(&Value<value_type>::getValue, _1)));
```

Comment: I think that needs to be `bind(avg,bind(&Value<value_type>::getValue,_1))`.

Comment: Er, yes: I didn't notice that `Value` is a template. In addition, it may be necessary to take the address of `avg` in addition to specifying the template argument. I'll update the answer...

Comment: This didn't work, but gave me a hint for finding a working solution. I'm hopeful that there is a simpler way than my version though so I modified the question and I am keeping it open for now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it look neater is to use [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html). You can shorten down to this:

```
std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), lazy(avg)(arg1.getValue()));
```

Heres how to do that. First thing you need to do is make the `avg` function object lazy. The simplest way to that is in-place with a function, defined like this:

```
template<class Function>
function<Function> lazy(Function x)
{
    return function<Function>(x);
}
```

Next thing you need to do is write a function object for getValue, that can be lazy, like this:

```
struct get_value_impl
{
    // result_of protocol:
    template <typename Sig>
    struct result;

    template <typename This, typename T>
    struct result<This(Value<T>&)>
    {
        // The result will be T
        typedef typename T type;
    };

    template <typename V>
    typename result<get_value_impl(V &)>::type
    operator()(V & value) const
    {
        return value.getValue();
    }
};
```

Thirdly, we extend the phoenix actors, using our `get_value_impl` class, so it will have a `getValue` method, like this:

```
template <typename Expr>
struct value_actor
    : actor<Expr>
{
    typedef actor<Expr> base_type;
    typedef value_actor<Expr> that_type;

    value_actor( base_type const& base )
        : base_type( base ) {}

    typename expression::function<get_value_impl, that_type>::type const
    getValue() const
    {
        function<get_value_impl> const f = get_value_impl();
        return f(*this);
    }
};
```

Finally, we put it all together by defining the argument and passing it into the for_each algorithm:

```
expression::terminal<phoenix::argument<1>, value_actor>  arg1;
std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), lazy(avg)(arg1.getValue()));
```

Comment: Very interesting technique. I will have to take some time to understand Boost.Phoenix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use boost, but not C++11 features, then I would consider using [the BOOST_FOREACH macro](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/foreach.html)

Yes, it's a macro, but as macros go it's well behaved

It's also reads quite nicely and is hard to get wrong

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const Value& rValue, values)
{
    avg(rValue.getValue());
}
```

C++11 range based for loops will replace it